# Enter button does not work at textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, newline, enter

I'm a beginner in c# and first time need your help, because I can't find any solution to this problem.
I make a typewriting tutorial, I have a richtextbox filled with randomly generated characters, spaces and 3 new line.
The user must type the characters in a textbox, and if he typed the adequate character the character turn to green in richtextbox and he can type the the next one. If he makes a mistake, he cant move to next character until the the right button was pressed.

My problem is everything works, except new line part.
When the program compare the 2 new line accept the new line but just when ctrl+enter was pressed, simple enter wont work, the program somehow thinks enter is a wrong character.
I need to make this user friendly and a simple enter needed for this.

I tried this so far:

Make textbox MultiLine makes no difference.

Changed Acceptsreturn to true makes no difference.

Changed in string that will be the text of richtextbox the Environment.Newline to \r and \n and \r\n and its makes no difference.

Changed the textbox to Richtextbox makes no difference.

I tried every possible combination above and I cant work out what is the problem.

Here it is the random character generating part:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    char[] karakterek = { 'a','á','b','c','d','e','é','f','g','h','i','í','j','k','l','m','n','o','ó','ö','ő','p','q','r','s','t','u','ú','ü','ű','v','x','y','z' };
    char[] nemkarakterek = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','"',',','+','%','/','=',':','-',};
    char egykarakter;
    string teljes = "";
    int mutato = 0;
    Random r = new Random();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        karakterfeltolt();

    }
    private void karakterfeltolt()
    {
        int hanyszor = 0;
        do
        {
            string egesz = "";
            if (hanyszor < 3)
            {

                do
                {
                    if (egesz.Length < 150)
                    {
                        if (r.Next(1,15)<14)
                        {
                            egykarakter = karakterek[r.Next(0, karakterek.Length)];
                            egesz = egesz + egykarakter;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            egykarakter = nemkarakterek[r.Next(0, nemkarakterek.Length)];
                            egesz = egesz + egykarakter;
                        }
                    }
                } while (egesz.Length < 150);

                if (egesz.Length > 150)
                {
                    egesz = egesz.Substring(0, 150);
                }
                int vanespace = 0;
                egesz = egesz.Insert(r.Next(2, 10), " ");
                for (int i = 0; i < egesz.Length - 10; i++)
                {
                    if (egesz[i] == ' ')
                    {
                        vanespace = i;
                        int eselynovelo = r.Next(0, 10);
                        if (eselynovelo > 6)
                        {
                            egesz = egesz.Insert(r.Next(vanespace + 3, vanespace + 10), " ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            egesz = egesz.Insert(r.Next(vanespace + 6, vanespace + 10), " ");
                        }
                    }
                }
                string nagybetus = egesz.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + egesz.Substring(1);
                nagybetus = nagybetus.Insert(nagybetus.Length, ".\r\n"); 
                teljes = teljes + nagybetus;
                hanyszor++;
            }

        } while (hanyszor < 3);

        richTextBox1.Text = teljes;
    }
```

And here is the textbox compare part:

```
private void textBox3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == richTextBox1.Text[mutato])
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
            richTextBox1.SelectionLength = mutato + 1;
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
            mutato++;
            label2.Text = "OK";

        }
        else
        {
            label2.Text = "Wrong";
            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }
```

What else can I do? Please help me.

Comment: Keep in mind that a newline is represented by two characters in your string: "\r\n". You need to match them both when Enter is pressed.

Comment: Also does not work with 

nagybetus = nagybetus.Insert(nagybetus.Length, ".\r");

nagybetus = nagybetus.Insert(nagybetus.Length, ".\n");

nagybetus = nagybetus.Insert(nagybetus.Length, "."+Environment.NewLine)

Comment: Try removing every \r of your string

Comment: Metacolon, then how I suppose to generate new lines?